# Maintaining Optical Margins with Hanging Punctuation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, luatex, microtype, protrusion

To achieve [hanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation) quotation marks, I am changing their protrusion settings in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{luatextra}
  \setmainfont{Times}
\usepackage{microtype}
  {
  \SetProtrusion{encoding=EU2}
  {\textquotedblleft={1000,},\textquotedblright={,1000}}
  }

\begin{document}

This minimal instance\\
of a left-side margin\\
“should help”\\
should help\\
to provide an example\\
of the issues faced\\
“of the issues faced”\\
with optical alignment\\
and hanging punctuation.

\end{document}
```

Since `microtype` performs protrusion only on the glyph closest to the margin, every glyph adjacent to a hanging quote receives no protrusion with this method. I want to maintain optical margin alignment in my text block, with the hanging quotes' adjacent glyphs protruded to align with the block.

Is there a way I can apply the appropriate protrusion to those adjacent glyphs? It cannot be font-specific, as I'd like to apply the same settings to any font.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Added full MWE.

Comment: Not your question but for use with LuaTeX, `tracking` requires the `fontspec` option `Renderer=Basic` according to the `microtype` manual (page 6).

Comment: Forgot to put that in MWE. Thanks. It's not really important though so I'll elide the tracking part.

Comment: When I run your MWE, setting the protrusion makes no obvious difference to the output at all. I had to comment the line calling Times and change to the article class to avoid errors etc. but apart from that, it has no visible effect. (I tried changing the value of the left quotation marks to 2000 and to 10 and could see no difference. So either the effect is real subtle or it doesn't work with Latin Modern or something is missing somewhere.

Comment: The protrusion may not work unless you use fontspec (called in my MWE via luatextra) and load a font (Times, Baskerville, Minion, etc.) not included with a TeX distro. The difference between 2000 and 10 should be quite unsubtle if it is working correctly.